# Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed. on Magento 2 Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, session

I have a Magento 2.2.4 running on a Windows IIS server. When entering checkout, I often get

> There has been an error processing your request

error. When I check the error report, it says *

> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

I can get past the error by refreshing the checkout page in my browser.

This happened rarely at first but has got more frequent now. Any idea what could be causing this?

Here's the full error from the report file.

> {"0":"Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction
>   failed.  ID: user (path:
>   C:/Websites/(website)/(directory)/var/session/) in
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Session\SessionManager.php
>   on line 508","1":"#0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2,
>   'session_regener...', 'C:\\Websites\\www...', 508, Array)\n#1
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Session\SessionManager.php(508):
>   session_regenerate_id(true)\n#2
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\Session.php(564):
>   Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->regenerateId()\n#3
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\generated\code\Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor.php(310):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Session->regenerateId()\n#4
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Index\Index.php(35):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor->regenerateId()\n#5
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index->execute()\n#6
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('execute',
>   Array)\n#7
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#8
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\generated\code\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute',
>   Array, Array)\n#9
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(107):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()\n#10
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage.php(161):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#13
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#14
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\generated\code\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#15
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#17
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#18
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#19
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#20
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#21
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#22
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#23
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#24
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#25
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#26
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('launch',
>   Array)\n#27
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#28
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch',
>   Array, Array)\n#29
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#30
>   C:\Websites\(website)\(directory)\pub\index.php(37):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#31
>   {main}","url":"/checkout/","script_name":"/index.php"}